# umbraco value doesn't show

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I'm working in local and I have my database in local.
But when I want to take an umbraco value it doesn't show anything. 
Like this

```
<ul>
   <umbraco:Item fieeld="contact" runat="server" />
</ul>
```

I have no idea why, someone who can me explain why?

Comment: you have a typo: fieeld

Comment: Yes, I changed but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If it's inside a template, the right way is this:

```
<umbraco:item field="propertyAlias" runat="server" />
```

But if it's inside a macro you must use:

```
Model.GetProperty("propertyAlias").Value
```